# Ajax reload method acting on a Django table

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, server-push

I currently have a simple HTML table which is being served by a django app in the following way:

```
<table id="List">
<th>
    <td data-field="ID" align="center">ID</td>
    <td data-field="Name" align="center">Name</td>
</th>

{% for item in filter %}
    # 'filter' is the result of applying some filter on a query set
    <tr value="{{ item.ID }}">
        <td align="center">{{ item.ID }} </td>
        <td align="center">{{ item.Name }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I would like this table to respond 'live' to changes in the database (e.g. a change to the 'Name' field for some record).  I have looked into server push solutions (django+twisted, django+swampdragon, django+angular) but they seem overly complicated for what I need here.

I then found out about $.ajax's [reload() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) which seems perfect BUT it seems from the examples I've found that I would need to form the table by passing jsonified records instead of what I am currently doing.

Can anyone advise me on:

- If this is a viable solution
- Explain how you might construct a table from a django database in
  such a way that ajax would be able to update the contents every few
  seconds.

Comment: It depends. Live update - web socket. High load - redis.

Comment: Ok, could you clarify?

Comment: Web socket allows you to push data from server. rather than browser request at every interval of time.

Comment: Would you like to use `DataTables` for any other features as well or only the `reload()` functionality? Because if it's *only* the reloading it won't be difficult to do this with plain jQuery and skip the overhead of an additional plugin. Regarding your question, roughly how many items will be in that table, at what interval are you planning the updates and how many users do you expect to be on that page at the same time?

Comment: Well the pagination and searching features are useful too.  But a jQ only solution would be useful too